# Multiple web servers sharing a public IP

Tags: apache, routes, virtualhost

I have two entries in my DNS: `www.domain.tld` and `svn.domain.tld`

Both point to my company's public IP address of `88.77.66.55`.

I have two apache servers serving port 80 on my LAN behind that public IP.  One hosts my website on `192.168.1.2` and the other hosts my SVN server at `192.168.1.3`.

I would like to route the IPs to:

```
www.domain.tld -> 192.168.1.2
svn.domain.tld -> 192.168.1.3
```

Here's my current intended design, but I don't know if it's feasible so I'm looking for feedback. My router will forward all port 80 data to `192.168.1.2`.  Then, on that machine:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
---
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.2:80
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.3:80

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:80>
    ServerName www.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.3:80>
    ServerName svn.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

Am I using the correct mechanism to accomplish this?  Can I use hostnames instead of IPs?  I'd like to get some indication of issues before I start messing with configurations and cause downtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that will work.  Nginx reverse proxy is another way to do this on a larger scale.